# I want my input field to always have two decimal places

Tags: javascript, html, input, currency

**For example lets say the user needs to type 112.56,**

So when **user types 1**, input field becomes **1.00**
Next when **user types 1 again**, input field becomes **11.00**
Next when **user types 2**, input field becomes **112.00**
Next when **user types '.' (the decimal point)**, input field still is **112.00**
Then **user types 5**, input field becomes **112.50**
Last **user types 6**, and input field becomes **112.56**

I've seen this achieved in my local atm machines, I'm wondering if this is achievable via html/javascript or requires a different language or a different technique

**I want it to update while the user is still typing**

Comment: Your question is good, except for the part where you are asking to exclude use of `toFixed()`, which has distracted people into downvoting you without reading the question properly. There is no reason to avoid using that function as part of the solution to your question.

Comment: Yeah I understand, I specifically used that phrase because I thought people would otherwise give me solutions that would only update my input on blur and not when typing, Thank you again bro, Your code works except a minor hickup (see comment of your answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById('n').onkeyup = e => {
  const process = i => {
    let v = i.value;
    const ss = i.selectionStart;
    const resetCursor = () => i.setSelectionRange(ss,ss);
    if(/^[0]*.00$/.test(v)) {
      i.value = '';
    }
    else if(/^[0-9.]+$/.test(v)) {
      let p = v.indexOf('..');
      if(p>=0) {
        i.value = v.replace('..','.');
        resetCursor();
        process(i);
      }
      else if([...v].filter(c=>c==='.').length>1) {
        let j = v.indexOf('.');
        i.value = [...v].filter((c,k)=>k<=j||c!=='.').join('');
        resetCursor();
        process(i);
      }
      else {
        i.value = (+v).toFixed(2);    
        resetCursor();
      }
    }
    else {
      v = v.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '');
      i.value = v;
      resetCursor();
    }
  }
  process(e.target);
}
```

```html
<input id='n'>
```

Comment: Thank you my bro!!!! A big virtual hug!!!!!

Comment: @supremeincubator no problem. Please edit your question to remove the toFixed() restriction

Comment: A minor issue, Let's say I typed 45. and then backspaced to remove the decimal point, At that moment the input updates to 4500.00 instead of 45.00

Comment: @supremeincubator yes, I noticed that too, but then if that is fixed, it's impossible for someone to attempt to remove the decimal place to change 1.00 into 100. They should use the left arrow to go back, instead of deleting the decimal place.

Comment: Can we sacrifice that perk for the code to work according to my desire? Is it possible?

Comment: The problem is that it's impossible to distinguish between someone pasting in the number 4500 and someone hitting backspace on the decimal when it shows 45.00

Comment: Also is there a way that I could use this coupled with ToLocaleString (I want commas and the currency symbol) Is it just too much to ask bro?

Comment: Doing commas for thousands etc and handling other possible locales makes it much more complicated, it would probably take me at least another couple of hours to think through how that would work and to implement it such that it is bug-free

Comment: I understand, Update me if you found out a way, Thank you!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249350/discussion-between-supremeincubator-and-andrew-parks).

Answer (score 0):

Make the input value to a `Float` with `parseFloat`. Then you can use `toFixed(2)` to always show 2 decimal spaces.

There is no real way around it. Use an EventListener to update it on input:

```js
let input = document.querySelector('input');

input.addEventListener('change', function() {
  let number = +input.value;
  input.value = parseFloat(number).toFixed(2);
})
```

```html
<input type="number" step="0.01" value="0">
```

Comment: Did you even read my question?

Comment: yes but it makes nos ense to exclude the only available methods for no reasons.

Comment: Your approach does not work as the user is typing, it waits for the user to click away or press enter